# MvvmCross URI Navigation Init deprecated

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm building an Android and iOS cross-platform app with `MvvmCross`. It uses [URI navigation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation?scroll=80#uri-navigation). I'm following the example and the URI I'm building supports two parameters:

```
[assembly: MvxNavigation(typeof(TestViewModel), @"myscheme://test\?param1=(?<param1>[A-z-0-9]+)&param2=(?<param2>[A-z-0-9]+)")]
```

I can use the parameters by overriding the Init function of the ViewModel just like in the example:

```
public void Init(string param1, string param2)
{
  Debug.WriteLine($"Started from url: param1: {param1}, param2: {param2}");
}
```

After some struggling with what to put in the `Activity` (Android) and `AppDelegate` (iOS), I finally got it working on both platforms (despite the lack of good documentation and examples). But now the question:
The example uses the deprecated Init function of the `MvxViewModel`. What's the alternative for passing multiple parameters like this? Is it possible to make it work with the new Prepare method? If yes, how?